# java.lang.NullPointerException when loading drawable which exists in each res/drawable-"density" folder

Tags: android

I have a drawable resource called obstacle.png which exists in each of my drawable-"density" folders.  Yet, whenever I run the app, I get a null pointer exception when I am assigning the bitmap's width to my _width variable.  This code will only run on mdpi and on the Galaxy TAB addon AVDs.  It fails on ldpi or hdpi AVDs.  Why?

```
19 public Weapon(Context context) {
20      super(context);
21      _weapon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.obstacle);
22      _width = _weapon.getWidth();
23      _height = _weapon.getHeight();
24  } //constructor



LogCat: 
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.shootball.Weapon.<init>(Weapon.java:22)
```

Answer (score 0):

`_weapon` is null since `BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.obstacle);` returns null.

Comment: Actually it only returns null if the image could not be decoded, otherwise it returns the decoded bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have obstacle.png image in all drawable folder.if there is no image it will return null value.